# Detect APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS action

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-permissions

Is it possible to track some action when `APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` is opened for Android Lollipop? When user opens application info from settings apps. As I can see there is action `android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART` but it requires some deprecated permissions.

I've found few examples on stackoverflow but they are not working, for example [Receive intent "android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS" for my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18427193/receive-intent-android-settings-application-details-settings-for-my-app).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When user opens application info from settings apps I want to receive an event.

Outside of *perhaps* through accessibility APIs (with user permission), this is not possible.

[`android.settings.APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` is an activity action](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS). There are no events raised as a result of activities being started to tell third-party apps "hey, the user launched this activity!" for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: Yeap I understand, maybe you know something about this event android.intent.action.QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART ?

Comment: @Orest: There is no such action in the Android SDK. I don't see where it is getting used on [Android 6.0](http://xref.opersys.com/android-6.0.1_r16/search?q=QUERY_PACKAGE_RESTART&defs=&refs=&path=&hist=&type=&project=abi&project=art&project=bionic&project=bootable&project=build&project=cts&project=dalvik&project=developers&project=development&project=device&project=docs&project=external&project=frameworks&project=hardware&project=libcore&project=libnativehelper&project=ndk&project=packages&project=pdk&project=platform_testing&project=sdk&project=system&project=tools), for example.